# Jest test file is not reading the env variable from .env.test

Tags: reactjs, testing, jestjs

```
describe('Testing', () => {
  it('Read ENV', () => {
    expect(process.env.REACT_APP_URL).toMatch("https://www.google.com")
  })
})
```

I have an .env.test file and it has the google url assigned to REACT_APP_URL:

```
REACT_APP_URL=https://www.google.com
```

When I run `npm test`, it shows this error

```
expect(string)[.not].toMatch(expected)
string value must be a string.
Received: undefined
```

Can someone tell me what went wrong? The .env.test is at the correct directory level because I am using .env.staging file and it is working.

Comment: please post https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: How do you load the environment variables from `.env.test` file?